# Creating a fixture in Specs 2

Tags: scala, testing, specs

Sometimes we need to mix in some traits in our test cases. However the following does not work:

```
"abc" should {
  "def" in new TraitA with TraitAB {
    // ...
  }    
}
```

To make it work, we do the following:

```
trait Fixture extends Before {
  def before = ()
}

"abc" should {
  "def" in new Fixture with TraitA with TraitAB {
    // ...
  }    
}
```

This feels somewhat hacky. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work if you also mix in the `org.specs2.specification.Scope` marker trait:

```
"abc" should {
  "def" in test {
    // ...
  }    
}

trait test extends TraitA with TraitAB with Scope
```